# Does a statement need to be a biconditional statement to prove by the contrapositive

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to write a proof and was wondering ***if a then b***, the converse ***if b then a*** might not be true. This leads me to wonder if the statement needs to be an ***if and only if*** statement if it can be proven by the contrapositive ***if not b then not a***.

That is do I need a statement like this ***a if and only if b*** to prove that ***if not b then then not a***, or is ***if a then b*** sufficient to do that.

Comment: Yes you are right, just changed it

Comment: In "regular mathematics", $a\implies b$ and $\neg b\implies \neg a$ are equivalent.

Comment: I think I know what is the problem with my statement. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $p\to q$ does not imply the converse, $q\to p$. For example, using a truth table, you can show that $p\to q$ is logically equivalent to the contrapositive:
$$p\to q \equiv \neg q \to \neg p$$
In other words, you do not need $q\to p$.

If you have that $p \leftrightarrow q$, then by definition you have that
$$q\to p.$$

---

If you are tasked with showing that $P$ implies $Q$, then one strategy is to show instead that $\neg Q$ implies $\neg P$, since $P\to Q \equiv \neg Q\to \neg P$. Thus, assume $\neg Q$ and arrive at $\neg P$. Then you have shown $P$ implies $Q$ since they are logically equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! You figured out what I was trying to say my bad. I have corrected my question above as well.

Comment: @Jam1 Sure, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, "$a \implies b$" means "not ($a$ and not $b$)". So then "(not $b$)$\implies$(not $a$)" means "not ((not $b$) and not (not $a$))". This simplifies to "not ($a$ and not $b$)", which is the same thing as "$a \implies b$". So yeah, you only need the one direction of implication.

You should probably think about this definition of $a \implies b$ if you've never seen it. Like, draw a truth table or something.